# PHP: Correct use of && in an if statment

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to ensure that both conditions are true in my statement. Is the following the correct way to do so?

I'm not sure of my bracket placement etc.

```
if((functionOne($paramOne) && functionTwo($paramTwo)) == condition){

....
```

Comment: What exactly is `condition` ?

Comment: what values do your `functionOne` and `functionTwo` return?

Comment: I just put these in as samples to make it easier to understand, im wondering about the placement of my brackets and use of &&?

Comment: no need to use the conditon... if you simply write: `if(functionOne($paramOne) && functionTwo($paramTwo))` if will enter the if body only when both the results of the two functions are `true`

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is

```
if(functionOne($paramOne) == condition && functionTwo($paramTwo) == condition){
```